# develop tabs using JSON

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs, android-tablayout

i want to know if we can develop tabs using JSON.i want as many tabs depending upon the categories in JSON and each tab must contain the list view if it is possible please let me know how to do it please

MainActivity.class

```
private void catmethod(){
        String url="http://www.souqalkhaleejia.com/webapis/menus.php";
        JsonObjectRequest catreq=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray menuarray=response.getJSONArray("menu");
                    for (int i=0;i<menuarray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject menuobj=menuarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText(menuobj.getString("title")));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuobj.getString("title"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    TabsAdapter tabsAdapter=new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),menuarray.length());
                    viewpager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
                    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("CatMenu", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(catreq);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fragment

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Fragment getInstance(int position){
        OneFragment fragment = new OneFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", position)
        fragment.setArgument(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        int position = getArguments().getInt("position", 0);

        // set your list base on position
        if(position == 0){
           //list 1
        } else if(position == 1) {
           // list 2
        } else {
           // list 3
        }
        return view; 
    }

}
```

Your ViewPagerAdapter

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private JSONArray jsonArray;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, JSONArray jsonArray) {
        super(manager);
        this.jsonArray= jsonArray;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return OneFragment.getInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return jsonArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("key");
    }
}
```

Tablayout setup

```
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    // get your json list
    JSONArray jsonArray = your_json_array; 
    for(int i = 0; i < yourJsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject json = yourJsonArray.get(i);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(json.getString("key")));
    }

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), yourJsonArray);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: i am getting this error sir  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: set fragment.setArgument(bundle); into public Fragment getInstance(int position). It forgoted. I also updated answer

Comment: i am not getting the title sir i had updated my Question sir please check it sir

Comment: sir i haven't understood it

Comment: I edited my answer, pass jsonArray into viewpageradapter instead of jsonarray length. try edited ViewPagerAdapter, hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Sir i got a doubt here there will be more tabs then how can i set different list data to the tabs sir at on create in the fragments sir

Comment: yes sir it solved me thank u sir but now my doubt is list view sir in the fragments sir

Comment: you can pass your jsonarray to fragment then set you list there, use recyclerview instead of listview. see this link http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105506/discussion-between-prominere-and-leonemob).

Comment: sir, i had tried recycler view but getting same list in every tab sir

Answer (score 0):

//JSON => [{"key":"TAB1", "list":[your list]}, {"key":"TAB2", "list":[your list]}, {"key":"TAB3", "list":[your list]}]

Using JSON you can add tab dynamically like...

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
// get your json list
JSONArray jsonArray = your_json_array; 
for(int i = 0; i < yourJsonArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject json = yourJsonArray.get(i);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(json.getString("key")));
}
```

Now using ViewPager you can display your list into Fragment base on your tab position.

This link will helpful to setup TabLayout [android-material-design-working-with-tabs](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

You can also your [google Gson](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON) library to parse your JSON object.

Comment: yes Sir i am using that tutorial only  but it have the fragments na sir for tab layout how can i do it sir

Comment: i am using volley sir

Comment: after created tab you can update your fragment list base on tab position or json object id.

Comment: set your tabs after received your json respons from volley

Comment: public void addfragment(Fragment fragment,String title){
        fragmentlist.add(fragment);
        tabname.add(title);
    }--i should not use this method na sir

Comment: Instead of add fragment from activity, get fragment from ViewPagerAdapter.

Comment: i am using FragmentPagerAdapter sir